# Are there official prices for all common magic items in Eberron?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, eberron, pricing

The default [list of common magic items](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items?filter-type=0&filter-search=&filter-rarity=1&filter-requires-attunement=&filter-effect-type=&filter-effect-subtype=&filter-has-charges=&filter-source=3&filter-source=2) is very short (and the PHB effectively has prices for 3 of the 4). My assumption has been that these are actually purchasable, unlike anything of a higher tier.

The *Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron* provides many more common magic items, but does not appear to list prices. Is there a source for this information somewhere?

Comment: WGtE, PHB, DMG, MM. (Plus a number of the Eberron sourcebooks from prior editions.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron*<sup>1</sup> p. 46 has a section on ["Creating Magic Items"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/wgte/welcome-to-khorvaire#CreatingMagicItems) with rules adapted from *Xanathar's Guide to Everything* and prices aligned with its ["Buying a Magic Item"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/xgte/downtime-revisited#BuyingaMagicItem) downtime activity. It suggests that House Cannith would be able to make many items at a much lower price, but common items look like they would be fairly priced at around 50 gp (probably more).

*Xanathar's Guide to Everything* p. 126 has the ["Buying a Magic Item"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/xgte/downtime-revisited#BuyingaMagicItem) downtime activity which is as far as I know the only way to buy magic items by RAW. The asking price for a Common magic item is listed as (1d6+1) x 10 gp, or half of that for a single-use item like a potion or a scroll. This isn't counting the 100 gp and one workweek of downtime spent finding a seller.

Normally there wouldn't be any guarantee that the particular item you're looking for will be for sale. To find a particular Common magic item your Charisma (Persuasion) check needs to beat a DC 10, with a +1 bonus for each additional workweek or 100 gp spent searching (up to a maximum bonus of +10). However, because Eberron is a high magic campaign XGtE suggests adding a +10 bonus to the check result which would mean that you can automatically find any given common magic item for sale.

---

<sup>1 It should be noted that WGtE is playtest material, and the official source for Eberron is *Eberron: Rising from the Last War*, which contains rules for common magic item prices as detailed in [Nobody the Hobgoblin’s answer.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/200364/62294)</sup>

Comment: FWIW, that section of the XGtE is prefaced as "optional rules" ... so calling it RAW might be a reach.

Comment: @Zach That kind of substantial edit may get rejected later by the post author. You might consider writing an answer yourself against that possibility.

Comment: It may be worth updating this answer now that *Eberron: Rising from the Last War* is out.

Comment: @VBlast: Updated for RftLW (made a new answer you can move it in here if you like)

Answer (score 7):

*Eberron: Rising From the Last War* introduces rules for common magic item prices on page 281, **Buying a Common Magic Item**:

> The DM sets the price of a common magic item or determines it randomly: **2d4 x 10 gp, or half as much for a consumable item** such as a potion or scroll.

This means prices would vary from 20 to 80 gp for a common magic item, with a typical price of 50 gp.

The section also discusses rules for items being available or not:

> In Eberron, common magic items can be found for sale in most communities.  The DM determines the stock that is available, or the DM has the shoppers make a group Intelligence (Investigation) check to find a shop or peddler that has the desired item in stock. The DC for this check is 10 in a city, 15 in a town, and 20 in a village. If the check fails, at least 24 hours must pass before looking for the same item in that community.