# What are the ways that I can access the spell Find Familiar via magic items or feats?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, familiars

After asking [if Revivify is commonly used](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/208703/83144), I started searching for ways that I could cast Find Familiar, since that was the only other spell that I had trouble justifying an entire feat for. Answers can include magic items that provide a 1st level Wizard spell, like the Witherbloom, Quandrix, and Lorehold Primers, or allow another PC to provide me the spell itself, like the Ring of Spell Storing. Feats are allowed also, but please exclude class and racial abilities if possible, as my character is already pretty much locked in on the path he'll take. Lastly, use official material only, with no third-party or UA sources.

Comment: If your character is pretty much locked do you want answers only available to your character? Magic items only usable by a druid for example may not be helpful.

Comment: @SeriousBri Not necessarily. The answer itself is useful to everyone, so I wouldn't want it to be hyper-specific to my case. Additionally, it doesn't necessarily have to be my character, as I mentioned that answers can include other characters supplying the spell. Thank you for the question of clarity though.

Comment: @JThompson We're here to solve *your* problem, though. Casting a wider net may bring a larger audience, but you have a problem you're trying to solve. Focusing on that isn't a bad thing, it's a good thing.

Comment: @NotArch I understand your point. Maybe I'm misunderstanding the usage of StackExchanges, but it seems to me there are two usages for asking a question:

1. Outsourcing a question to receive answers to a specific dilemma.
2. Outsourcing a question to receive answers to a general dilemma, so as to acquire pieces to solve one's own specific dilemma.

Personally, I see the second as more useful, as it helps me to understand the general principles to judge other situations by, harkening to the saying, "Give a man a fish, he'll eat for a day; teach a man to fish, he'll eat for life."

Answer (score 4):

It's technically by way of a feat, but if your campaign allows the Strixhaven backgrounds (some don't, as they're overpowered relative to most backgrounds), choosing **Lorehold Student**, **Quandrix Student**, or **Witherbloom Student** all give you the school's associated version of the **Strixhaven Initiate** feat for free as part of the background, which grants you two cantrips (from a list of three) and a 1st level spell from one of two spell lists. Those three schools have the Wizard list as one of their options, and can therefore provide you with *Find Familiar*. You can cast it once a day for free, and it's a known spell that can be cast with any other spell slots you have, should you need to do so.

Aside from that, there are two other feats that will grant access if you choose the Wizard spell list variant of the feat:

- **Magic Initiate**
- **Ritual Caster**

A **Ring of Spell Storing** is another option, being a moderately cumbersome but reusable way of achieving this with no direct resource cost if someone *else* in the party can cast the spell (just the time cost of attuning it to someone else to store the spell in it for you, then reattuning it back to yourself). (Per @Senmurv) The **Spell Bottle** (from Explorer's Guide to Wildemount) is a more convenient equivalent (no attunement shuffle required), but it's also a Legendary rarity item, where the ring is merely Rare, so (according to the usual magic item rarity by level guidelines) the bottle wouldn't be available until level 17.

Comment: ...or a scroll as well, maybe?

Comment: Maybe also add the ring of spell storing, that one should work, too.

Comment: @Senmurv: Scrolls are pretty unlikely to be useful, since they need to be on your class's spell list to use them, and **Find Familiar** is only on the Wizard list. Sure, a Thief at 13th level can use them, but that's pretty restrictive. Aside from that, only Wizards, Arcane Tricksters and Eldritch Knights (maybe a couple others with Wizard list access?\) could use them.

Comment: @NobodytheHobgoblin: True, added that in. It's cumbersome (the person who can cast has to spend a short rest attuning the ring, casting Find Familiar into it a few times, then the person who wants to cast it has to reattune it), but at least it's possible.

Comment: @ShadowRanger A bard that took *find familiar* via Magical Secrets could us a *find familiar* scroll, but that’s entirely irrelevant, so I’m just making useless observations.

Comment: @Senmurv: If another PC uses the scroll, *they* get a familiar, not the OP's character. The Ring of Spell Storing is different there, since (with some reattunement rigmarole) the other PC could store the spell into the ring such that the OP's character can cast it; same goes for Spellwrought Tattoos. The scroll can be made by another PC, and used by another PC, but unless the OP's character is one of the extremely limited cases where they can cast spells from the Wizard list, the OP's character cannot make use of such a scroll at all.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I see. I hadn't thought of that. Thanks for taking time to explain. Thinking of the Ring of Spell Storing, would the Spell Bottle from the Explorer's Guide to Wildemount work as well? ...once it's been emptied of its original spell.

Comment: @Senmurv: Yep, looks like it. More convenient to use than the Ring of Spell Storing, but far harder to acquire (the ring is Rare, the bottle is Legendary). Probably not worth waiting for 17th level for your build to come online. :-)

Answer (score 4):

If you can get yourself a [Spellwrought Tattoo](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/2408275-spellwrought-tattoo) of Find Familiar spell, anyone can use it, and it doesn't require attunement. Using the Spellwrought Tattoo doesn't require spellcasting ability, unlike Spell Scroll, which requires the spell to be in your class spell list.

It is one-time use only, but probably okay for Find Familiar, since the result is permanent (until the familiar is killed).

(Some backstory: my monk character in a PBP campaign is also looking to get a familiar. We have easy access to magic items, and without taking a feat or multiclassing, Spellwrought Tattoo is the only considerable option I have. It requires no attunement, and is not too expensive in the server I play in. Ring of Spell Storing takes an attunement, although for Find Familiar arguably you can just borrow it to cast it once then returns it, but it's not allowed in the server I play in.)

Comment: That's not a bad solution if magic items are available for sale. Since it's a one-use common magic item, [the cost of a tattoo would be something like 20-45 GP according to the few rules available for pricing magic items](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/129072/28941) (it's 10-35 GP, plus the 10 GP cost of materials for that particular spell, which presumably get incorporated into the price of the item). That's within the bounds of reason, and low enough you won't feel cheated too much if the familiar dies and you have to repurchase the tattoo.

Comment: Yep. In the server I play in, the tattoo are actually priced more expensively (250gp for 1st level, 1000gp for 2nd level, 3000gp for 3rd level), but you can re-ink at 25% cost. The spell selection is on a randomized shop that changes every few days. The idea is so that players don't simply cover their bodies full with tattoos, haha (one body can easily fit 42 1st level tattoo)

Comment: Hi @justhalf  Good thinking! For the reference, info on the Spellwrought Tattoos is found in Tasha's Cauldron of Everything, p. 135.

Answer (score 2):

## Buy it as a service from a lvl 10 Chronurgy Wizard using Arcane Abeyance

The feature allows the wizard to cast a spell into a bead, and whoever releases the spell from the bead is treated as the caster of the spell. This gives you a single cast of the spell, but can be purchased again if needed.

Comment: For the reference, info on Arcane Abeyance and motes is found in Explorer's Guide to Wildemount, p. 184